Why LLM's train for only one epoch?
Why it is so crucial to NOT let the model see same texts for multiple times as we do for example in computer vision? Or should it actually be the other way around and due to the fact that we have small datasets of images, we are forced to train several times on the same ones?

I don't think there is such a strict requirement.
From a quick glance - I checked the GPT-2 paper, the GPT-4 report and the Llama paper - only the last one mentioned something about epochs

Overall, our entire training dataset contains roughly 1.4T tokens after tokenization. For most of our training data, each token is used only once during training, with the exception of the Wikipedia and Books domains, over which we perform approximately two epochs.

The famous LLMs have billions of weights, so if they were trained for too long they could obviously easily memorize most of their training set and would become useless.
Now why for at least one LLM it happened to be just about 1 epoch, I don't know and it is an interesting question.
It could be that the authors targeted specifically this number in setting the learning rates. It could be that some combination of their performance metrics stopped improving after $\approx 1$ epoch (perhaps by coincidence?). On the other hand it is probably difficult to find good validation metrics in this context. You can't just exclude some random texts: it is not easy to guarantee that the training set does not spill over to the validation set or benchmarks at a more abstract language level and this can lead to an undesirable optimum in an overfitted state. So it could have also been partly a subjective choice by the Llama team.
